# Angular build production not working on Safari

Tags: angular, safari

On Chrome working good
On Safari throwing error below :

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '..._angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ɵɵdefineComponent"]...')
```

Anyone have a solution for it? thanks, or can we debug to find which component error?

I want to find a solution to run it on Safari

Comment: can you please post your code ?